# cannot access phpmyadmin database in xampp server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I installed `xampp` to my system. Then opened `httpd.conf` file in notepad and `modified server name and server admin` i.e; I changed the localhost to my system ip address. In config.inc.php, I changed the Server ip which was `'127.0.0.1'` to my system ip address. Then I opened XAMPP control panel, installed Apache and MySql and started it. I clicked Admin button in front of Mysql button to open the database. It displayed `'Host cannot connect to mysql server'`. Then I opened `XAMPP for Windows command prompt`. There I got error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql
 -u root' at line 1
```

Am I missing any configuration settings which is not allowing to connect to database? I have checked the document root. The path is correct. I am not getting where I went wrong.

```
Setting environment for using XAMPP for Windows.
rakshitha@OCEANMLRLP02 c:\xampp
# mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 7
Server version: 5.5.36 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> mysql -u root;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql
 -u root' at line 1
```

Comment: `mysql -u root` is a shell command to connect to mysql server as user `root`. Since you are already inside of mysql monitor, it wants a query, not a shell command, so thats why there is an error; its a shell command, not a query.

Comment: XAMPP is pretty much a working instance of all this stuff installed out of the box. You're doing a lot of tinkering with things that should "just work". For instance, try rolling back your change of `config.inc.php`; in this case I believe the XAMPP kit blocks MySQL connections from non-local connections and when you changed the IP address you're connecting to, you affect how PHP talks to MySQL (making it a network connection from an IP address other than 127.0.0.1). Probably your user is only set to connect via localhost or 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What went wrong is that you're already logged in :) "mysql -u root" is a command to login to mysql server. "mysql>" prompt indicates that you're already in and you should use MySQL commands in here, as you did in fact in line "mysql> show databases;".

Comment: Ok. I did not know this. I am new to this. I can access the database. I saw the address and it is localhost:8082/phpmyadmin. But, instead of localhost, I want to connect using my system IP address so that I can access this database remotely. I don't what configuration settings should be done to achieve this?

Comment: You have to have possibility to set up ssh connection to your server, then after this you're simply using "mysql -u <username> -p". For ssh connection use linux terminal or putty on windows.

Comment: I just want to clarify my doubt. Does the line in config.inc.php, 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1'; mean that the 'phpmyadmin database should run in the server with ip address '127.0.0.1'.

Comment: I think it does. Remember one thing: don't change localhost/127.0.0.1 to other addresses. This is the definition of your local machine. If you want to point out to other address/domain you should do this by configuring routes on your router and/or dns (i.E. changing hosts definitions).

Comment: Ok. I will try it out.

Comment: When I debugged my website which is connected to phpmyadmin database, I got an error saying 'Lost connection to mysql server at “Waiting for initial communication packet” error 0'. I added 'skip_name_resolve' in my.ini file which I found in http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30725/waiting-for-initial-communication-packet-error-0-in-mysql. Then, I couldn't access database. The error message was 'Host '127.0.0.1' cannot access database' So, I removed that line. Then I could access database. Could you give some ideas to solve my problem.

Comment: I don't understand. You've got error, then added 'skip_name_resolve' and couldn't access db and after removing this line you could access db. Where's the problem if you can access db?

Comment: I want to solve this error.'Lost connection to mysql server at “Waiting for initial communication packet” error 0'. In my connection string, I have <add name="OMMainConnection" connectionString="Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=192.168.1.15;Port=8082;Database=abc;User=root;Password=;Option=3;"/>. Here, the connection is not opening.

Comment: Now, I am able to run the website. In connection string, I changed 192.168.1.15 to localhost and it works.

Comment: So everything is good now? Do you have problems still? If it's all please mark answer as accepted.